# Get related field names in serializer when ForeignKey is pointed to 'self'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a category model which has a field parent. This field can be null, and point to other categories from the same model. I'm having trouble serializing the category, and getting a list of its children using django rest framework.

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):

    ...
    name = models.CharField(
        _('category name'), 
        max_length=255, 
        unique=True
    )
    slug = models.SlugField(
        _('slug'),
        max_length=50,
        help_text=_(
            'A slug is a short label for something, containing only letters, numbers, underscores or hyphens. They’re generally used in URLs.'
        ),
    )
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        'self', 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        related_name='category', 
        blank=True, 
        null=True
    )
    ...
```

serializers.py

```
class CategoryChildrenSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    children = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ['children']

    def get_children(self, instance):
        if instance.parent is not None:
            queryset = Category.objects.filter(parent=instance.parent.id)
            return queryset


class CategoriesNavigationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    children = CategoryChildrenSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('name', 'children')
```

Ideally i want the response to look something like:

```
{
    name: Category 1,
    children: [
        {
            name: Category 2,
            slug: ...
        },
        {
            name: Category 3,
            slug: ...
        },
     
    ]
}
```

It also important to note that i want to stop on the second child level, even if the parent has grandchildren.

I have tried `children = serializers.StringRelatedField(source='parent', read_only=True)` and also doing the `get_children` method inside the `CategoriesNavigationSerializer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't return ***queryset object*** to your `serializers.SerializerMethodField`, it should be a clean serialized result, like `str`, `int`, `float`, `list`, `dict`, `None`, etc.

Try to change your `get_children` into this:

```
def get_children(self, instance):
    if instance.parent:
        queryset = Category.objects.filter(parent=instance.parent)
        return queryset.values_list('id', 'name', 'slug', flat=True)
    return []
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **`CategoriesNavigationSerializer`** serializer class to return serializer result from **`get_children(...)`** method

```
class CategoryChildrenSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    children = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ['children']

    def get_children(self, instance):
        return CategoriesNavigationSerializer(
            instance.category.all(),
            many=True
        ).data
```